# Custom TikZ node with svg path not clipped

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, svg, dimensions

I would like to make a custom node shape with a small picture (on north east) using the `svg` directive of TikZ, because the picture comes from a svg path.

As you can see with this simple code, the picture is clipped and I don't want to add text (aaaa) to make the attached node larger.

It would be great if you can show me how to operate a scale and a shift on this small picture. All my tests failed!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\tikzset{ 
  t1/.style={rectangle,fill=blue!20},
  t2/.style={path picture={ \draw[fill=red,draw=blue] svg "M0,0L10,10L20,0L10,-10Z";} } 
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[t1](A) at (1,1){A}; \draw(A.north east) node[t2]{aaaa};
\node[t1](B) at (2,1){B}; \draw(B.north east) node[t2]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) `:)` You don't need to add 'thank you' or sign your post. This is the way we keep it concise; your username automatically appears at the bottom of your posts.

Answer (score 6):

I have drawn the shape centered around zero and smaller such that you can adjust the inner sep more comfortably.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\tikzset{ 
  t1/.style={rectangle,fill=blue!20},
  t2/.style={inner sep = 2mm,path picture={ 
        \draw[fill=red,draw=blue] svg "M-3,0L0,3L3,0L0,-3Z";} 
        } 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[t1](B) at (2,1){B}; \node[t2] at (B.north east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're posting code faster than Lucky Luke is shooting! `:D`

Comment: The 'inner sep' fix my clipping problem, but what about shift and scale? I cannot change svg path data and I have to apply a 'shift+scale' on the small picture."\draw[fill=red,draw=blue,scale=.1] svg "M-30,0L0,30L30,0L0,-30Z";}" does not work.

Comment: @pelinquin Then you can see the edited version of my answer where I did a hack. After that modified to the current answer. You can add an xshift option to shift further.

Comment: @percusse. Sorry but I don't want xshift on the raw data. Why `\draw[fill=red,draw=blue,scale=.1] svg "M-30,0L0,30L30,0L0,-30Z";}` does not work?

Comment: @pelinquin You might want to provide the `xshift` to the node placement like `at ([xshift-1cm]B.north east)` when placing it. By the way this is required if you want to adjust further as a prediction ;) it is not essential. The reason for the weird behavior is that the path picture is clipped by the node shape with smaller size so you have to first make the node shape big enough such that it is visible and then scale it down. and after the scaling you might want to better position it.